# DateTime error while picking date in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to display daytime using a separate function unless it's returning the following error:

*Error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.
lib/screens/add_analyse_patient.dart:81

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  onClicked: pickDate(context)),*

Here is the code:

**button_widget.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonHeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onClicked;

  const ButtonHeaderWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.text,
    required this.onClicked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => HeaderWidget(
        title: title,
        child: ButtonWidget(
          text: text,
          onClicked: onClicked,
        ),
      );
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onClicked;

  const ButtonWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onClicked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
          primary: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: FittedBox(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: onClicked,
      );
}

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;

  const HeaderWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          child,
        ],
      );
}
```

And the function with which i'm trying to display the time:

```
Future pickDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final initialDate = DateTime.now();
    final newDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
    );

    if (newDate == null) return;
  }
```

And finally the widget where the error occurs:

```
ButtonHeaderWidget(
                    title: 'Date',
                    text: 'Select Date',
                    onClicked: pickDate(context)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the onClicked to: onClicked: () => pickDate(context))